# Multiple Update Panels

Tags: asp.net

When you have multiple UpdatePanels on a page, is there a way, in the code behind, find out which Update Panel triggerred the postback? It appears that the `Request["__EVENTTARGET"]` is not a reliable way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

An UpdatePanel doesn't trigger PostBacks, it intercepts them. The originator of the PostBack would be something like a button. If you have event handlers for all your interactive elements, you naturally know which one fired by which event handler runs.

Comment: Yes, I should have said "control in an Update Panel triggerred the postback". I have multiple instances of the same user control that has an updatepanel within it.

Comment: @unknown so the event handler in the correct instance of the user control should fire. It might be easier to help if we know what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the id of the postback element on the client with the following

```
function pageLoad(sender, args) {

// add function to the PageRequestManager to be executed on async postback initialize
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
      prm.add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest);   
}


function InitializeRequest(sender, args) {
    if(args._postBackElement.id === 'id_of_element_in_question' {              
        // do whatever
    }         
}
```

to get it on the server, presumably you'll know which control/event raised the postback as it will be handled in the relevant event handler in the code-behind.